# Deleting duplicate x values and their corresponding y values

Tags: python-2.7, duplicates, repeat

I am working with a list of points in python 2.7 and running some interpolations on the data. My list has over 5000 points and I have some repeating "x" values within my list. These repeating "x" values have different corresponding "y" values. I want to get rid of these repeating points so that my interpolation function will work, because if there are repeating "x" values with different "y" values it runs an error because it does not satisfy the criteria of a function. Here is a simple example of what I am trying to do:

```
Input:
x = [1,1,3,4,5]
y = [10,20,30,40,50]


Output:
xy = [(1,10),(3,30),(4,40),(5,50)]
```

The interpolation function I am using is `InterpolatedUnivariateSpline(x, y)`

Comment: 1) What programming language/tools are you using? 2) are your X values sorted?

Comment: python 2.7, and yes they are sorted in ascending order

Answer (score 0):

have a variable where you store the previous X value, if it is the same as the current value then skip the current value.

For example (pseudo code, you do the python),

```
int previousX = -1

foreach X
{
    if(x == previousX)
    {/*skip*/}
    else
    {
        InterpolatedUnivariateSpline(x, y)
        previousX = x /*store the x value that will be "previous" in next iteration
    }
}
```

i am assuming you are already iterating so you dont need the actualy python code.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but if anyone is interested, here's a solution with numpy and pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
x = [1,1,3,4,5]
y = [10,20,30,40,50]

#convert list into numpy arrays:
array_x, array_y = np.array(x), np.array(y)

# sort x and y by x value
order = np.argsort(array_x)
xsort, ysort = array_x[order], array_y[order]

#create a dataframe and add 2 columns for your x and y data:
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['xsort'] = xsort
df['ysort'] = ysort

#create new dataframe (mean) with no duplicate x values and corresponding mean values in all other cols:
mean = df.groupby('xsort').mean()
df_x = mean.index
df_y = mean['ysort']

# poly1d to create a polynomial line from coefficient inputs:
trend = np.polyfit(df_x, df_y, 14)
trendpoly = np.poly1d(trend)

# plot polyfit line:
plt.plot(df_x, trendpoly(df_x), linestyle=':', dashes=(6, 5), linewidth='0.8',
color=colour, zorder=9, figure=[name of figure])
```

Also, if you just use argsort() on the values in order of x, the interpolation should work even without the having to delete the duplicate x values. Trying on my own dataset:

[polyfit on its own](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTEFe.jpg)

[sorting data in order of x first, then polyfit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aRhI.jpg)

[sorting data, delete duplicates, then polyfit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlhYp.jpg)

... I get the same result twice